# Stateful Functional Component re-rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I'm trying to find out a reason why I'm getting so many re-renders on my `App` component.

I'm using a neat little lib `use-trace-update` and it's letting me know that my props change only two times, but I'm re-rending 28 times...

#### Things I've tried

Making sure dispatch to props shorthand is being used [as mentioned here](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2018/04/02/redux-rerendering/), that means my dispatch shouldn't cause a rerender. And since my props only change two times, I just don't get it!

I've also wrapped the `App` component in `React.memo`, it's a component using hooks. But no avail.

```
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(App);
```

I don't know if this matters, but it seems this happens on my computer not my colleagues computer. I've attempted to change branches, delete `node_modules` but it still isn't working. I'm not totally sure what else to check.

**note** I'm determining rerenders with a simple `console.count("Rerender")` in my code. Maybe there is a better way? I guess this doesn't tell me the difference between re-instatiation and re-rendering.

P.S. the reason I care is that there is a ton of dispatches triggered. I'd also just like to understand! :smile:

Comment: Rerendering is fine, only in extreme cases you should pay attention to them.

What is wrong is the multiple dispatches, please share code.